# javascript set border style 0px

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm new to javascript so please forgive my naive question!

I just want to set border style to 1px visible when mouse enters an image, and back to 0 when mouse leaves.
Here is what I've done so far:

```
function cardMouseEnter(ctrl) {
    document.getElementById(ctrl).style.border = "solid 1px";
}

function cardMouseLeave(ctrl) {
    document.getElementById(ctrl).style.border = "solid 0px";
}
```

With IE it works fine while with Firefox and Safari, once the border is set to 1px, it won't go back to 0px.

I'm sure there is a catch... I KNOW it can be done in the html tag of each object, so please avoid telling me that...

Comment: Can't answer your question without seeing the code that calls those functions

Comment: You are not showing all of the necessary code. How are you calling the cardMouseEnter and cardMouseLeave functions? You would have to bind to the mouseover event in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `none` ?

```
function cardMouseLeave(ctrl) {
    document.getElementById(ctrl).style.border = "none";
}
```

If you want to use `0` I think the correct syntax is simply `0` without the "solid" or "px".

Answer (score 0):

If you are only toggling border width then address only border width

```
document.getElementById(ctrl).style.borderWidth = '1px';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the code you show us. See http://jsfiddle.net/4x2qU/ - border shows up when the mouse is over the word "test" and disappears again once the mouse is moved away. It is working even though I left the mistakes from your example: border color isn't being set (defaults to "black") and it is toggling all border parameters instead of changing border width only.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was **onmouseleave** DOESN'T EXISTS outside IE!

I replaced it with **onmouseout** and now its working just fine with all 3 browsers...